# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.StandardChildDTProxy', but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a template in Umbraco via visual studio. I've replicated a working view model (looking to exclude one html entry) but each time I load this new template I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.StandardChildDTProxy', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'TSW.Web.ViewModels.StandardChildVM'.

I've tried various methods as I've reached the conclusion its to do with the view model to no luck. Can anyone highlight what is causing this?

Controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AutoMapper;
using TSW.DocumentTypes;
using TSW.DocumentTypes.Factories;
using TSW.Model;
using TSW.Web.Controllers.Base;
using TSW.Web.ViewModels;

namespace TSW.Web.Controllers
{
public class StandardChildController : BaseRenderController<StandardChildDT>
{

    private readonly ISitePageFactory _pageFactory = null;

    public StandardChildController(ISitePageFactory pageFactory)
    {
        _pageFactory = pageFactory;
    }

    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Hour")]
    public ActionResult StandardChild()
    {
        var model = Mapper.Map<StandardChildVM>(CurrentContent);
        model.InnerPageHeader.ShowHeading = true;
        model.InnerPageHeader.Title = model.PageTitle;

        return View(model);
    }}}
```

View Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TSW.Model;
using TSW.Model.ViewModel;

namespace TSW.Web.ViewModels
{
public class StandardChildVM : PageContentVM
{
   public List<LinkItem> ChildPages { get; set; }
   public Image ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
   public Image MainImage { get; set; }
   public string Synopsis { get; set; }
   public List<FileModel> Downloads { get; set; }
   public List<CtaItem> CaseStudies { get; set; }
   public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}}
```

Umbraco Document Template:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TSW.DocumentTypes.Converters;
using TSW.DocumentTypes.NonPageItems;
using Vega.USiteBuilder;

namespace TSW.DocumentTypes
{
[DocumentType(Name = "Standard Child Page", Alias = "standardChildPage", IconUrl = "icon-umb-content",
    AllowAtRoot = false, AllowedTemplates = new[] {"StandardChild"},
    AllowedChildNodeTypes = new[] { typeof(ReviewDT) })]
public class StandardChildDT : PageBaseDT
{

    [DocumentTypeProperty(UmbracoPropertyType.MediaPicker, Mandatory = false, Name = "Main Image",
        Alias = "mainImage", Tab = TabNames.Media)]
    public int MainImage { get; set; }

    [DocumentTypeProperty(UmbracoPropertyType.MediaPicker, Mandatory = false, Name = "Thumbnail Image",
        Alias = "thumbnailImage", Tab = TabNames.Media)]
    public int ThumbnailImage { get; set; }

    [DocumentTypeProperty(UmbracoPropertyType.TextboxMultiple, Name = "Page Synopsis", Alias = "pageSynopsis",
        Tab = TabNames.Content, Description = "A short summary text that appears on listing or search pages")]
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }

    [DocumentTypeProperty(UmbracoPropertyType.Other, Mandatory = false, Name = "Case Study Ctas",
        Alias = "caseStudiesCtas", OtherTypeName = "Cta Picker",
        CustomTypeConverter = typeof (CommaSeperatedNodeIdConverter), Tab = TabNames.Content)]
    public List<int> CaseStudiesCtas { get; set; }

    [DocumentTypeProperty(UmbracoPropertyType.Other, OtherTypeName = "Multiple Media Picker",
        CustomTypeConverter = typeof (CommaSeperatedNodeIdConverter), Name = "Downloads",
        Alias = "downloads", Tab = TabNames.Downloads)]
    public List<int> Downloads { get; set; }
}}
```

HTML Template:

```
@using TSW.Web.Helpers
@model TSW.Web.ViewModels.StandardChildVM

@{
Layout = "~/Views/_Master.cshtml";
}

<section class="section section--short section--padding-large">

<div class="columns">


    <article class="columns__main">
        <section class="article">
            @if (@Model.MainImage != null)
            {
                <div class="article__image-outer">
                    @Html.Image(@Model.MainImage, new { @class = "article__image" })
                </div>
            }
            <div class="article__wysiwyg">
                @Model.PageContent
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>


</div>
</section>

@Html.Partial("_CTAs", @Model.CaseStudies)

@Html.Partial("_Reviews", @Model.Reviews)
```

Comment: the error comes from sending a StandardChildDT object to the view instead of a StandardChildVM.  Either change your model in the view to StandardChildDT or figure out why our are returning a StandardChildDT instead of the expected StandardChildVM

Comment: @rogerdeuce - I had thought thats what I am doing on the HTML template with "@model TSW.Web.ViewModels.StandardChildVM?"

Comment: that line is telling the view what to expect.  However your controller is sending the view a StandardChildDT type object instead, and your view is confused.  Hard to tell without stepping through it, but I believe this line is not giving you the object type you think it is:  var model = Mapper.Map<StandardChildVM>(CurrentContent);

Comment: @rogerdeuce - Okay thanks for clarifying - I'm mapping this in another .cs as follows: `config.CreateMap<PageBaseDT, PageContentVM>() .Include<StandardChildDT, StandardChildVM>()`
would that not point the object to the vm?